# Draw order in XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

It is possible to set draw order of a `DrawableGameComponent` by setting `DrawOrder` property. But is it possible to set draw order of "main" `Game` class?

I have 2 DrawableGameComponents, and Draw method of a main Game class is called first, while I want it to be the last. Should I just mode all "main" draw code to another component and set it `DrawOrder`?

Comment: Yes you should :)

Comment: @RoyT. seems like I'm just confused myself a little. Black on black, that's why I didn't saw it. Main `Draw` is called last, as expected. I'll remove question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to clarify: Inside `MyGame.Draw` there is usually a call to `base.Draw`. It is my impression that this line is responsible for drawing attached components. Whatever code you put above it will be drawn before, whatever you put below it will be drawn after. If you remove the call to base, presumably the components will not be drawn.

If you have components A, B and C, and you would like `MyGame.Draw` to draw A and B, then draw some of its own stuff, and then draw C, it seems you'd have to draw each component manually by iterating through `MyGame.Components`.

Comment: Thanks, this certanly clarifies situation. Rather then remove my question, I will mark this as answer, since it might help others.